# Cost effective solution to upload large files on S3 using application running in EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, large-files

I have an application running on EC2 instance. Using that application user can large file 10MB+ on S3 bucket. The mechanism I am copies the file on EC2 instance and then upload it on S3 bucket. It is costly because two times copy (first on EC2 and then on S3 bucket). I have tried using another solution in order to reduce two-time copy a file.

API-gateway ==>> lambda function ==>> S3 bucket.
API gateway has a limit of 10MB i.e. file size should be less than 10MB.

I thought of splitting the file into small pieces but again lambda have to zip them (it again takes time to zip them).

The other solution is s3 pre-signed URLs but it is again costly. I need some effective solution for this problem

I found solutions but they were not either cost effective or time consuming.

Comment: S3 presigned URLs are **NOT** costly, especially not compared to any other solution you might come up with. That is the cheapest method, do you actually understand how S3 pricing works?? What part of presigned urls is "costly" according to you? https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/

Comment: Oh sorry, got you! there is no cost attached with pre-signed URLs. The S3 cost depends on S3 storage classes. For standard it depends on data in GB in/out to S3. Overall i did not find any cost attached with pre-signed URLs

Comment: And you do not pay for "data in", you only pay for the request itself, a whopping $0.000005 per PUT request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S3 pre-signed URLs is the way as mentioned by luk2302.